# How do I get the content of a HTML drop-down box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list as part of a form.  It calls a JavaScript function as its action, and its content is one of several strings.

In that function, I need to get the string that the user selected.  I came across a function that lets me get the index number of the item selected, but as the contents of the list may vary, it's effectively useless.  Is there a method that lets me get the actual string that the user entered, perhaps with the DOM and `getElementById()`, or with JQuery?

I considered using a textfield, but that brings up the possibility of errors related to the interface.

Comment: You use some ambiguous terminology here and you show no code, which only compounds our difficulty discerning what you need. Is it that you need to get the value of the `<option>` `.on('change')` and send that value to a `function`?

Comment: You can get the text of the selected option in all browsers using `selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text` where *selectElement* is a reference to a select element. Note that if no option is selected, the selected index will be -1 so you might want to check that `selectElement.selectedIndex >= 0 ` first.

Comment: *get the actual string that the user entered* - in a `select` box, users don't *enter* anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure what you want but from what I understood maybe [this is it](http://jsfiddle.net/xyXPz/1):

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option value="1">This is the first one</option>
    <option value="2">This is the second one</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**
You seem to want the text of the option, not the value.

**second edit:**
using Rob's suggestion in the OP so we don't need to iterate.

HTML

```
​<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
  <option value="alpha">one</option>
  <option value="beta">two</option>
  <option value="gamma">three</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById('myselect')​​​; //get our select by its ID
mySelect.addEventListener('change', function(evt){
   return evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].text;  
});
```

​

Note that *addEventListener* does not work on Internet Explorer 8 and below, so you need to use *attachEvent*.  This should give you a pretty good idea though. 
For further reference see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

​​